# BASH Question: Incrementing 2 variables to produce a file that looks like 200001.txt, 200002.txt, etc

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I got the first section to create the years, but getting the months and incrementing them is stumping me.

```
#!/bin/bash
varRan=$(( $RANDOM ))
newdir="testing_"$varRan
#echo  $newdir

mkdir $newdir
cd ~/$newdir
for   ((i = 2000; i<= 2022 ; i++; )); do
        for  ((m = 1; m<= 12 ; m++; )) do
        touch $i$m".txt"
done
#       touch $i$m".txt"
done
```

Comment: printf: `printf -v filename '%4d%02d.txt' "$i" "$m"; touch "$filename"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a shell expansion with a leading zero does what you need.

```
#/bin/bash

newdir="testing_$RANDOM"

mkdir "${newdir}"; cd "${newdir}"

for y in {2000..2022}; do
    for m in {01..12}; do
        touch "prefix_$y$m.txt"
    done
done
```

Comment: Or `touch prefix_20{00..22}{01..12}.txt`

Comment: Freaking awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @Freddy: Much better than mine. Succinct, saves running 275 processes, and no issues with length of command line args.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date` for generating dates in shell with custom format

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d -d "2002-03-28 +1 days" 
2002-03-29

$ date +%Y-%m-%d -d "2002-03-28 +1 months"
2002-04-28

$ date +%Y-%m-%d -d "2002-03-28 +1 years" 
2003-03-28
```